# VSCode requires me to re-select my python interpreter each time it starts

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[edited!]
Everytime I start Microsoft Visual Code, I get the following alert:

[image]

This behavior started a few days ago (after a windows's update). I can select the python interpreter and after that, everything works just fine. From within vscode, I can open a terminal in my virtual environment and I can launch the debugger for django.

[image]

The problem is that once I quit vscode, it forgets. Next time I start it up, I have to repeat the process. I have to do it every time.

My environment is:

Windows 11
wsl2
Ubuntu 22.04
pyenv (python 3.9.15 selected)
poetry

I've tried the following:

1. Researched issue.
2. Tried Python: Clear Cache
3. Rollback of Python extension to version 2021-02. Restored to latest.

I'm out of ideas at this point. Is this a configuration issue? Any other ideas on how I can resolve this? This may be an extension issue, but I want to make sure I'm not doing something incorrect with visual code.

Comment: Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. Try to write less conversationally, and get right to the point. Carefully [edit] to avoid redundancy and [noise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721). It's also unclear what you mean in several places, e.g. "I've tried pasting in the python I have in my launch.json into the terminal and it runs python just fine." - I don't see any Python code in that file (and it wouldn't make sense for there to be any) - did you mean the Python *interpreter path* specified in the JSON config file?

Comment: You are welcome to report bugs to the developers, https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues, not here.

Comment: Similarly, when you say that you "Tried downgrading and upgrading" - tried downgrading and upgrading **what**? To what version(s)? How? What effect did this have? In general, spend less (ideally zero) talking to us as if you want to have a conversation, and more time explaining step by step so that we can envision the situation as accurately as possible.

Comment: That said, yes, if you suspect a bug in someone else's program, we are not equipped to help you with that.

Comment: Please remove everyhting from your prepro details that are not required to reproduce the problem. For more guidance, see the instructions on how to create a [mre].

Comment: Have you tried to roll back to the historical version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this was an extension issue. I followed the github link to the python extension project and found a recently closed bug that looked similar. One of the comments suggested I try the pre-release version and my issue is no longer reproducible. Thanks everyone for the help.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/20644